# C# Entities loop give wrong value in editorFor when doing an order

Tags: c#, entity-framework-4

I have a problem with the editorFor and multiple editable data.

If i remove the orderby Name for the settings all is working as it should be (see controller code).
When i add the orderby Name something strange happens.

In my view the displayFor has the correct value but the editorFor has an incorrect value!
It seems like the editorFor is using the sorting as is in the database and the displayFor is using the sorting of the list.

Is this a bug or am I doing something wrong?

My controller:

```
public ActionResult Index()
{
    List<Setting> settingList = db.Settings.OrderBy(x => x.Name).ToList();
    return View(settingList);
}
```

My view :

```
@model List<DataAccess.Setting>      
@for (int x = 0; x < Model.Count(); x ++)
{
    <div class="row">
        <label class="col-md-3">@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => Model[x].Name) </label>
        <div class="col-md-8">
            @Html.EditorFor(modelItem => Model[x].Value)
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => Model[x].Value)
        </div>
    </div>
}
```

Comment: The view isn't getting refreshed after the Ordering.

Comment: How should i do that? Because now I'm do the order before calling my View. It doesn't make any sense that displayFor has correct value and editorFor not

Comment: n.v.m. i've found it, ModelState.Clear(); did the trick. Thx for pusing me in the right direction!

Comment: It is a common issue that controls don't automatically call the paint method for refreshing after data get changed.  Either using a Clear method or setting data to null will call paint.